# Rapid UI prototyping for consumer product

Tags: prototype, tools

I am searching for a tool which helps me to create a basic UI mockup for a consumer product. When I am searching online I only find tools that are aimed on website design and computer software ui design. It has to be very simple however it would be nice if I could have some sort of interaction.

Comment: Does the UI have physical as well as software components ?

Comment: Why is "aimed on website design and computer software ui design" not what you need? Are you trying to prototype a physical product? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_printing#Home_3D_printers

Comment: Please provide more details. Typically, for physical objects, you'd build a model. The 'tool' would be foam, clay, knives, 3-D printers, 3-D modeling software, wood, plastic, molds, etc, etc.

Comment: Call me crazy but I do my best work (that isn't drawn out by hand) on Keynote, and that's nowhere near being designed for a UI tool.

Comment: He's clearly looking for a tool for a physical product. Are we all so blind to the "real world" here that no one can get that?

Comment: @Charles only thing that is *clear* is that he is not looking for software UI nor website UI prototyping tools. "Consumer product UI" could be dials on a microwave, buttons on a remote control, TV's GUI or—to some extent—handles of scissors. I hope the question gets updated; until then, your answer is the only one that could be considered valid of the lot.

Comment: @koiyu - but all of those things you mention *are* physical products, or at least part of a physical product.

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD or any 3D modelling software should give you what you are looking for. I haven't dealt with CAD in many years, so I wouldn't be able to tell you if there's anything free or cheap out there that does decent 3D modelling.

Answer (score 0):

We use http://keynotopia.com/. uses keynote or powerpoint into the best rapid prototyping tool for creating mobile, web and desktop app mockups.

Also running it on an actual devices gives extra UX feedback.

Comment: The person is looking for a physical product design tool not mobile, web...

Answer (score -2):

I would think there would be some stencils/widgets available for visio/omingraffle/axure.  Do none of these offer the elements you require?  It's hard to say without further information.

Comment: Read the question - he's looking for a design tool for a physical product, not a computer UI

Answer (score -2):

Here's a collection 11 free and very good tools for wireframing and prototyping: [10 FREE TOOLS](http://speckyboy.com/2010/01/11/10-completely-free-wireframe-and-mockup-applications/)

> 1. [Pencil Project](http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/)
> 2. [Web Site Wireframe Tool](http://wireframe.talltree.us/default.asp)
> 3. [Hot Gloo](http://hello.hotgloo.com/)
> 4. [DUB - DENIM](http://dub.washington.edu:2007/denim/)
> 5. [Mockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com/)
> 6. [MockFlow](http://www.mockflow.com/signup/)
> 7. [Prototype Composer](http://www.serena.com/products/prototype-composer/index.html)
> 8. [fluidIA](http://www.fluidia.org/)
> 9. [Cacoo](http://cacoo.com/)
> 10. [Lumzy](http://www.lumzy.com/)
> 11. [iPhone Mockup Web App](http://iphonemockup.lkmc.ch/)

However, I often use [Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks.html) for prototyping and it actually works, take a look at that too.

Comment: Read the question - he's looking for a design tool for a physical product, not a computer UI

Comment: oh  you're right, thanx